# Looking for documentation on JS Object.constructor() (method)

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I have seen code similar to the following:

```
var obj = Object.constructor("args", ...other parameters...)
```

(See line 11 & 25 : https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/html-audio-in-pjs/5702257898455040)

Which appeared to be a method of building an object from supplied text.  Every search I try turns up info on object constructors and nothing about a constructor method on the internal Object object.  The docs at mozilla do not include a constructor function (method) on the Object object.

Can anyone point me toward info about using this function?

Comment: Ok I see now, and boy that's a really bad thing to put in teaching material. It's like a cooking lesson that involves touching the stove.

Comment: That is very possible, I will look into that a bit more closely.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object` is a function therefore its constructor is `Function` so `Object.constructor` is actually `Function` and that can be called as:

```
var fn = new Function("a", "b", "return a + b");
console.log(fn(1, 2)); // 3
```

But that is as bad as `eval`, so please never use this..

Comment: AHA!  A bit of misdirection I had not seen!  That is definitely what is happening. The people at KhanAcademy inject code to safeguard against beginner mistakes (endless loops, etc) and I am looking to bypass injection into time critical code.  (pixel manipulations)    Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the MDN documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Comment: Been there (as stated) that is a property, not a method.  It returns the object constructor.  Thanks for trying!

Comment: I think it's both, property and (reference to a) method! "_Returns a reference to the `Object` constructor **function**_". Likely, in you example that function contains the code to set the object properties.

Comment: Yeah its a bit blurry as the very next sentence states: "Note that the value of this property is a reference to the function itself"  But as its normal use is without parentheses, I'd call it a property.

Answer (score 0):

The `constructor` property simply points to the function (`Function`) that was used to construct the object.

Example:

```
function Bla() {
    console.log('a');
}

let a = new Bla; // Logs "a"
console.log(a.constructor); // Logs ƒ Bla() { console.log('a') }
a.constructor(); // Logs "a"
```